# How to connect to IBM MQ without using username and password If am trying to connect getting this error? I am not supplying username and password

Tags: spring-boot, authentication, security, ibm-mq

```
 public MQQueueConnectionFactory mqQueueConnectionFactoryB() {
    MQQueueConnectionFactory mqQueueConnectionFactory = new MQQueueConnectionFactory();
    try {
        mqQueueConnectionFactory.setHostName(host2);
        mqQueueConnectionFactory.setQueueManager(queueManager2);
        mqQueueConnectionFactory.setPort(port2);
        mqQueueConnectionFactory.setChannel(channel);
        mqQueueConnectionFactory.setTransportType(WMQConstants.WMQ_CM_CLIENT);
        mqQueueConnectionFactory.setSSLCipherSuite(sslCipherSuite);

    } catch (JMSException e) {
        log.error("Failed in connection establishment" + e.getMessage());
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return mqQueueConnectionFactory;
}
```

Failed in connection establishmentJMSWMQ2013: The security authentication was not valid that was supplied for queue manager 'QM1' with connection mode 'Client' and host name 'xxxxxxxx'.
com.ibm.msg.client.jms.DetailedJMSSecurityException: JMSWMQ2013: The security authentication was not valid that was supplied for queue manager 'QM1' with connection mode 'Client' and host name 'xxxxxxxx'.
Please check if the supplied username and password are correct on the queue manager to which you are connecting.  For further information, review the queue manager error logs and the Securing IBM MQ topic within IBM Knowledge Center.
at com.ibm.msg.client.wmq.common.internal.Reason.reasonToException(Reason.java:531)

Comment: This JMS error is just a mapping of MQRC_NOT_AUTHORIZED which could mean one of a plethora of things, e.g. wrong password, no password, blocked by IP address, missing authority. In order to discover which, view the qmgr AMQERR01.LOG for full details.

Comment: I dont have username and password to give i.e. I want to connect without username and password.I dont have access to get Qmgr log any other way to troubleshoot

Comment: @MoragHughson added configuration

Comment: You would need to ask the MQ admin what error is in the logs.   2035 is by its nature vague and covers many different situations, the error in the AMQERR01.LOG will be more specific.

Comment: You cannot guess how to solve a security problem without access to the qmgr log - deliberately - otherwise you could just hack it! :-D Find your qmgr admin and get a look at the error log.

Comment: My issue is resolved there was some security setting on the server side which was blocking me .